# Why was my edit to someone's question automatically rejected?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I spent some time fixing up the formatting for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957706/selection-sort-used-to-sort-a-linked-list) and it was automatically rejected.  Is it because the question has several downvotes?

Comment: Sorry, I was searching more for automatic rejection rather than community user rejecting it, so yeah, this is a duplicate I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't rejected automatically. The question was edited in the same second that [your suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/231487) was rejected.

So, what happened is: The OP edited the question, and thus had to clear your suggested edit first. He clicked the "Improve" button and marked your edit as unhelpful, which makes Community reject it.

Even though the rejection vote apparently came from Community, it was the asker who rejected your edit.

Comment: Gah, alright thanks lunboks. :)